# Check if script is loaded already. If not, load it asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to load the jQuery JS asynchronously and then i want to call some callback methods when it is completely loaded. 
I might be using the same code block over and over again. So i want to check if jQuery(or any other script) is already added before actually adding it.If it is already loaded/loading, then the callback of the current call should be appended to that of the previous call. This is what i'm trying to do.

```
/*BP Asynchronous JavaScript Loader*/
if (typeof bp_onload_queue == 'undefined') var bp_onload_queue = [];

if (typeof bp_dom_loaded == 'boolean') bp_dom_loaded = false;
else var bp_dom_loaded = false;

if (typeof bp_async_loader != 'function') {
    function bp_async_loader(src, callback, id) {

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.async = true;
        script.src = src;
        script.id = id;
        //Check if script previously loaded.
        var previous_script = document.getElementById(id);
        if (previous_script) if (previous_script.readyState == "loaded" || previous_script.readyState == "complete") {
            callback();
            alert("had already loaded the same script completely");
            return;
        } else {

            script = previous_script;
        }
        if (script.onload != null) previous_callback = script.onload;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var newcallback;
            if (previous_script && previous_callback) newcallback = function() {
                previous_callback();
                callback();
            };
            else newcallback = callback;
            if (bp_dom_loaded) {
                newcallback();
            } else bp_onload_queue.push(newcallback);
            // clean up for IE and Opera
            script.onload = null;
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
        };
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (!previous_script) head.appendChild(script);
        else alert("had already started loading that script but not complete.so we appended to the previous script's callback");

    }
}

if (typeof bp_domLoaded != 'function') function bp_domLoaded(callback) {
    bp_dom_loaded = true;
    var len = bp_onload_queue.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bp_onload_queue[i]();
    }
} 
/*JS gets loaded here */

bp_domLoaded();

/*Loading jQuery Asynchronously */
bp_async_loader("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js", function() {
    alert("script has been loaded : 1");
}, "jQueryjs");

bp_async_loader("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js", function() {
    alert("script has been loaded : 2");
}, "jQueryjs");
```

Can someone please let me know if there are any errors in this code or if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: The usual better way is to not do that - add jquery to the pages that need to use it, and don't add it to the pages that don't. If you're using some sort of framework on the server it might have tools so that we can declare that particular modules assume certain scripts being present in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :). This code is for a JavaScript plugin and i will be reusing the same scripts in different plugins.So i wanted to eliminate the same scripts being loaded again.I was trying to do something similar to what FB does for loading it's JavaScript SDK.

Comment: You could use the google loader to load jquery, or at least look at how they do it. I think you need an API key for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar and found this
http://themergency.com/an-alternative-to-jquerys-getscript-function/